# npm publish/typescript How can I avoid the ugly import when consuming my npm typescript package?

Tags: angular, typescript, npm-publish

I've just worked with Angular 2 (typescript) for a while, and very sorry if my questions is so noop :(

I published my first package to npm as following

**project structure**

```
lib
|--banana
   |--b.js
   |--b.d.ts
|--coconut
   |--c.js
   |--c.d.ts
src
|--banana
   |--b.ts
|--coconut
   |--c.ts
gulpfile.ts
package.json
tsconfig.json
typings.json
```

**package.json**

```
"name": "XXX",
  "main": "lib/",
  "typings": "lib/",
  "files": [
    "lib/"
  ]
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "outDir": "lib/",
        "types": [
            "core-js"
        ]
    }
}
```

I publish it to npm successfully, then I consume it in one angular-cli project via

```
npm install my_package --save
```

The problem is that in the consuming project, I only can import the class of my package via the absolute path, for i.e

```
import {Banana} from './../../node_modules/my_package/lib/banana/b'
```

I tried some changes in the way to publish my package, but it has not still worked as expected.

So, please help me to show the point I missed in the way I publish my package or the way I consume my package?

**EDIT**
If I import as following:

```
import {Banana} from 'XXX';
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve XXX relative to /Users/john/Documents/workspace/consuming-npm/src/app/app.module.ts., resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/john/Documents/workspace/consuming-npm/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /Users/john/Documents/workspace/consuming-npm/src/app/app.module.ts  

ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module build failed: Error: /Users/john/Documents/workspace/consuming-npm/src/app/app.module.ts (18,33): Cannot find module 'XXX'.)
```

And this is the structure of [consuming-npm]:
[image]

I think the problem is around the way I publish my npm package, but still don't know where it comes from :(

Answer (score 2):

In you package.json, update the main script:

```
"main": "lib/banana/b"
```

You can then import it using the name you specified in your package.json (`XXX` in youryou sample code above)

```
import {Banana} from "XXX";
```

Comment: apply your suggestion, however, I meet this error                                       `ERROR in ./src/app/app.module.ts
Module build failed: Error: .../src/app/app.module.ts (18,33): Cannot find module 'XXX'.)`                                                                                               Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a `package.json` in `src`?

Comment: I updated my question to give more information about my consuming project. Thank you very much!